# Can UITableView be used to create a grid?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, user-interface

IS it possible to create the list of contacts or friends (Facebook for example),3 in a row ?
For example like 3 friends image with their name below in the first row and next three in the next row and goes on till the contacts are over. which can be selected for further process. Is there a API for this ??

Just like the home screen of iPhone or better example would be the application "Tap to chat"

Comment: So you want something like a grid that is loaded with your friends in a format similar to the iPhone home screen?

Comment: Thats exactly I want ..i just want where to start for it , any info will be really useful !! thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

Well there are a couple ways that you could do this, so I'm just going to throw out what makes sense to me. As far as I know there is no API specifically built for this.

How I would do this is to programmatically create my grid made of UIButtons. You would be storing these in an array of course, and I don't know if you have any ideas on if you would limit how many on a screen or per "page". Afterwards you could go through your array and change the background images of the buttons, effectively creating an Image Button(I don't know for sure, but something like this might already exist). It shouldn't be terribly hard, you just have to define for yourself what it is exactly that you want, how it interacts with its surrounds, etc.

Another option would be to create a very simple view that contains your image and your label, and the programatically create instances of this, though I don't think that adding button functionality would be as easy. It is still very possible I just don't know how to do it off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `UITableView` with a custom cell with whatever you want in it, load those 4 images and names of the persons depending on the row number . To get the custom cell, create an `IBOutlet` to the cell and use this method.

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customCellView" owner:self options:nil];
```

To make a cell, make a new Nib/Xib file which is blank, make files owner the class with the cells, drag a `UITableviewcell` object out and put whatever objects you want on top of that view, set background as clear color and when you load the nib, enter all info into those images and labels. GL

Comment: So you want to add multiple people into one cell? Just curious how you would be able to tell which one was selected? An very interesting option though!

Comment: add buttons with tags(you could use two digits first one for row number second for column number) and set these tags at run time depending on the indexpath in  cellForRowAtIndexPath. Set its selector to a single method and when its pressed, make sure you get :(id)sender so you can get the tag in the method that is called. From there call whatever methods you want in selector.